# AWS Batch custom logging from container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

Is there any way to create custom **cloudwatch** stream logging name for each job in **AWS Batch**? Something like this:

```
> docker run --log-driver="awslogs" --log-opt awslogs-region="eu-west-1" \
  --log-opt awslogs-group="my-group" --log-opt tag='{{.Name}}-{{.ImageName}}-{{.DaemonName}}' \
  busybox echo test
```

How can I supply the arguments such as **awslogs-group** and **tag** or **aws-log-stream** with a job name for each running job?

Comment: Good question! Have you found a solution for this in the meantime? So far I haven't found a glow say to associate between any of the job parameters, the job ID or anything related to the job and the log stream ID created by CloudWatch...

Comment: @PaulMichalik I asked AWS support team and they said it's not possible for now. Therefore, to monitor the jobs I logged job id and some custom identifier for each docker container and search them in Cloudwatch.

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no way to customize the CloudWatch log streams in advance. If you think about it it even makes sense - a lot of things get much easier for them. Instead you can get the name of the log for this job from the response of a call to the `DescribeJobs` API

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned, it even makes sense. Here's a link to the docs: [DescribeJobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobs.html) By the way, I am  a victim auto correction - it should have been "I haven't found a way to associate..." in my first comment. Can't edit anymore...

Comment: Ah Thanks for mentioning that. I will have a look.